# Visual Studio Code debug mode issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm sorry to bother , I don't know if I can ask this
Visual Studio Code, suddenly can't use debug mode to set interrupts to test.

It seems that it is talking about the folder name problem, but after accessing the folder, it will not be renamed. How can I solve it now?  I can't upload photos so I'm capturing the important parts.

```
i.e.: the module "queue" could not be imported because it is shadowed by:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/queue/__init__.pyc
Please rename this file/folder so that the original module from the standard library can be imported.
```

Not sure how to change folder name or duplicate name, these actions are forbidden after accessing the folder, or is this some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an actual issue in VSCode - https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/886

In case you're using python 2.7, Downgrading the python VSCode extension should help.